# What is the meaning of a dashed line connecting two notes on different staves?

Tags: piano, notation

I want to play this song on the piano and I don't know the meaning of the dashed line connecting the two F notes in measures 8 and 16. [image: score image]

Comment: All I see is "image not available".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a "voice leading line".  Use is sometimes a bit ambiguous, meaning either a musical or an execution suggestion.  You might want to take both and play it with the right hand as a continuation of the right hand melody line.  That would likely imply sorting out the fingering of the preceding passage to end on one of the fingers that make it natural to jump one octave down.

Of course, the continuation makes this a bit artificial.  You still might want to try how it sounds since it usually is a bit easier to match character while using the same hand.

Answer (score 2):

The dashed line indicates that the note at the bottom of it is connected to the right hand melody.  Regard that note as part of the melody.

Comment: What is the implication of this connection of the lower F to the right hand melody? Is it an indication to play it with the right hand?

Comment: Not necessarily. It's just too low to write in the treble clef, so they put it in the bass clef for convenience.